# Conditional Formatting based on whether or not time is present

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, client-side-rendering, formatting

Is there a way to set background color conditionally ony when data is present?

Only when someone sets a time due it shows up in the column and I want to make that more visible.

I am familiar with setting a condition based on `.innerHTML=` but is there way to express if a value is present apply background and if not do nothing.

Edit 1

I am using this code in a script editor currently. I want to also be able to highlight a cell under the "Time" column when it is not blank.

```java
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("TD");
  var i=0;
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
  {

    if (x[i].className=="ms-vb2") 
    {

      if (x[i].innerHTML=="Request")
      {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor="#ed2a2a"; 
      }

      if (x[i].innerHTML=="Assigned")
      {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor="Yellow"; 
      }

      if (x[i].innerHTML=="Arrived to Modality")
      {
        x[i].style.backgroundColor="Green"; 
      }

     }

   }

</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to achieve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId);
          if(rows[i]["Followup_x0020_Date"] != "")
          {
            row.style.backgroundColor = "#dff0d8";
          }


       }
     }
   }); 

});

</script>
```

Note: you need to change "**Followup_x0020_Date**" to your Date column.

The result is:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I to combine what you provided me with the code I was already using but it did not work.  Nor did it work when just using the code you provided alone.